# Reading a .txt file line by line into multiple text boxes with buttons in a c# windows form

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, split, text-files

I have got a txt file with 10 lines in it, each line is a record with 5 different fields;
Farrell,Jade,Louise,2011/09/13,F

I am using the commas to split record by FamilyName, FirstName, MiddleName, EnrolmentDate and Gender. I want each field to have its own text box then use buttons to look through the different records.

Everything so far is working under the load button which reads the data from the file and puts it into the text boxes using the code below which works but it only shows the first record so i want a buttons to show the next record, previous record, first and last record and also a button to sort the data from A-Z by the family name. Any help on how to go forward would be great! thanks!

```
private void Load_BT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
    OpenFileDialog filechooser = new OpenFileDialog();
    StreamReader filereader = new StreamReader("StudentFile.txt");  
    String inputrecord = filereader.ReadLine();
    string[] inputfields;

    if (inputrecord != null)
    {
        inputfields = inputrecord.Split(',');
        FamName_TXT.Text = inputfields[0];
        FirstName_TXT.Text = inputfields[1];
        MiddleName_TXT.Text = inputfields[2];
        Enrolment_txt.Text = inputfields[3];
        Gender_TXT.Text = inputfields[4];
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("End of File");
    }         
}
```

Comment: You've asked a lot of questions here can you clarify exactly what you need help with?  Also, what solutions have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some design issues here, but i will address your immediate concern. The problem is you only read one line. You need to iterate over all the lines in the textfile. I am assuming you want the load button to load all the data at once.

```
string[] allRecords = filereader.ReadAllLines();
foreach(string inputRecord in allRecords) {
    string[] inputfields = inputRecord.Split(',');
    //insert the textbox.Text += inputfields[0] + "\n"; etc
}
```

if you want a single button to resort the data across all the textboxes.

1. you really should create a class called Person with properties that correspond to your fields and override compareTo so you can sort by last name or maybe use linq to do the sort for you.
2. you need a list that will host all of these person objects
3. from there you can populate the textboxes accordingly
4. Create a sort button that will reorder the list or create a new list and repopulate the textboxes.

1-3 would be done in the load button. The reason for the person class is because you want all the data you read in from the file to be associate with an object. if you try to do the sorting directly from the textboxes as you seem to be trying to do you will run into issues such as how to make sure the data doesnt get jumbled. It certainly may be possible but it is not an elegant way and would be more work in my mind